# Coding a 2d Follower Using C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, I'm pretty new at coding video games and I'm trying to code a follower sprite. I want it to be similar to how Mortys follow Ricks in Pocket Mortys. How they are a few steps behind on the path Rick makes. Everything that I try either the follower stays on the same side of the sprite it's following, or it rotates, but as a 3d follower and doesn't go in the right spot. What should I be doing? Please and thank you!

Edit: The code I have on the follower is:

using UnityEngine;

using System.Collections;

public class FollowTheBoy : MonoBehaviour

{

```
private GameObject wayPoint;
private Vector3 wayPointPos;
private float speed = 1.5f;

void Start()
{
    wayPoint = GameObject.Find("The Boy");
}

private Vector2 target;

void Update()
{

    target = wayPoint.transform.position;

    transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, new Vector2(target.x - 1, target.y - 1), speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

}

Comment: Can you some code that you already tried? Maybe we can give you some useful hints and get to a solution together?

Comment: You can code a follower by recording all the movements of the target character (or at east a small, recent subset), then playing them back on the follower's code a few tics behind.  The more followers, the further back in the played back list they should start.  I've used this technique in multiple video games and it works great.